# Autocomplete Search with Nuxt and Vuex?

Tags: nuxt.js, vuex, algolia

Can anyone advise which is the best approach in achieving the following?

I have a Nuxt.js project where I need to create a search input that will provide autocomplete suggestions when a keyword is being input.

Below is what I have so far and I had been thinking of achieving the above with Algolia. Do you think this approach is right or shall I pursue this with JavaScript only?

Would highly appreciate if someone could provide the suggestions using a snippet as well:

```
<template>
    <label class="block">
    <span class="text-gray-700 font-bold">{{ label }}</span>
    <input
        type="search"
        class="mt-1 block rounded-md border-0 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 bg-transparent"
        autocomplete="off"
        :placeholder="placeholder"
        v-model="keyword"
    >
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
        <NuxtLink to="/">
          {{ item }}
        </NuxtLink>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <pre>
      {{items[0]}}
    </pre>
  </label>
</template>

<script>
  import { defineComponent } from "@vue/composition-api";

  export default defineComponent({
    setup(props) {},
    data() {
      return {
        keyword: "",
        hasInput: false,
      };
    },
    computed: {
      filteredResults() {
        let tempItems = this.items;
        if (this.keyword != "" && this.keyword) {
          tempItems = tempItems.filter((item) => {
            return item.icao.toLowerCase().includes(this.keyword.toLowerCase());
          });
        }
        return tempItems;
      },
    },
    props: {
      label: String,
      placeholder: String,
      items: {
        type: Array,
        required: false,
      },
    },
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Depends of your needs, do you think you do need Algolia here?

Comment: @kissu, to be honest - filtering the items prop with a method on input would do the job better. However I’m not sure how to structure my method to achieve that ..

Comment: How would you do that in vanilla JS? Filter elements on some specific letters?

Comment: My goal is to provide a keyword to the input element that will be used to filter the objects within the ´items` array. The objects have the following keys: id, name, city, country, iata, icao.

Comment: Does this one help? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#find_an_object_in_an_array_by_one_of_its_properties

Comment: @kissu, yes - that works! But there is one more thing that I need to complete my function, do you know how can I `find` the results based on an approximate input? Basically filter the array as I type in the input.

Comment: This is what `find` is doing already no?

Comment: @kissu, with `find` I only get a match returned if my input is exactly the string I am searching for. For example, if I input 'banana', I get returned the whole 'banana' object, while if I am typing 'ana' I am not returned anything, even thought I want to be suggested object that contain this string in their `name` (banana, ananas etc.)

Comment: Just got the below computed property to almost work, however I still get 'error during evaluation' on it. Do you maybe know what is missing?

Comment: Please do not post code in comments. Rather edit your initial question and format/highlight it properly.

Comment: @kissu, my bad - I edited the original code now, with the updated computed property that almost filters my results based on the keyword. I tried debugging for a while and came to understand that calling the `.toLowerCase()` function on `item.icao` returns the 'error during evaluation'....maybe you know what is wrong in my function that I get this message?